# ADB not working with Samsung Galaxy A20e

Tags: adb, samsung, usb, usb-debugging

I wish to connect via ADB to a Samsung Galaxy A20e, but my computer won't detect the phone. I'm running Arch Linux and `lsusb` doesn't show anything about this phone when it's connected via USB.

**What I've tried:**

- enabled USB Debugging in Developer Mode
- set "Transferring Files" as the Default USB Configuration
- set "MTP + ADB" in the view that appears after dialing `*#0808#`
- tried different USB cables on different USB ports and even on different computers (all running Arch Linux though)

But still nothing: `lsusb` remains unaware of this phone.

What else can I try to get a Samsung Galaxy A20e to communicate with my computer so I can use ADB?

Comment: I would boot into a "standard-distribution" live-Linux system (like Ubuntu) and check if it also can not detect your phone. If it is not detected a hardware defect on the phone is very likely.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like there's [an official wiki for using ADB on ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Android_Debug_Bridge). Have you tried it?

Comment: Try "sudo lsusb"